# Flex 3 DataGridColumn HeaderText Localization

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, flex3, localization

I'm working in a multi-language application using ResourceBundle in Flex 3. I'm displaying data in a DataGrid and defined DataGridColumn headerText like this

```
headerText="{localizedHeaderText('LABEL_USER_NAME')}
```

this function returns the localized label for the username, but when I dynamcally select another language evertying gets refreshed but the headerText labels?

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Unless you make the localizedHeaderText method bindable, the binding will never be re-evaluated since it does not know about the change event of the resourceManager.

Assuming you are in a UIComponent subclass, you'll need to do the following:

1. override resourcesChanged and dispatch a custom event
2. add [Bindable(event="customEvent")] above the method

Sample code:

```
override protected function resourcesChanged():void {
    super.resourcesChanged();
    dispatchEvent(new Event("localeChange"));
}
```

and

```
[Bindable(event="localeChange")]
public function localizedHeaderText(key:String):String {
    return resourceManager.getString('resources', key);
}
```