# Flex 4 DataGridColumn: Function Binding to headerText dose not work

Tags: apache-flex, datagridcolumn, headertext

i have a big problem to bind this method:

```
[Bindable(event=LOCALE_CHANGED_EVENT_TYPE)]
public static function localeString(pathInLocale:String):String
{
    var value:String=LocaleUtil.getValueFromLocaleFromStringPath(pathInLocale);
    if (value == null || value.length == 0)
    {
        value=pathInLocale;
    }
    trace(value);
    return value;
}
```

like this:

```
<mx:DataGridColumn headerText="{PDMPlusPlusModelLocator.localeString('employeeView.employeeFilter.noDottedManager')}" />
```

The Binding seams simply not beeing executed. (Think that, because the trace() is not called and i have debuged it)

But the same works perfect here:

```
<mx:Label text="{PDMPlusPlusModelLocator.localeString('employeeView.employeeFilter.noDottedManager')}"/>
```

Dose anyone have an idea what the Problem is?

Note: i reade [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516843/flex-3-datagridcolumn-headertext-localization) and i think it's the same problem, but it do not work for me cause of any reasons:

Comment: I try a little and the Binding works if i Bind a method that is located in the same mxml as the DataGrid. But that is not what i want.
I want to have a general localeString function, and not have to write one per mxml :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies here: [Bindable(event=LOCALE_CHANGED_EVENT_TYPE)]

This is a preprocessor rule that hasn't done a resolve on its references yet. Effectively what the [Bindable] does is to write an event listener for you (via a ChangeWatcher elsewhere), and since they are based on 'magic strings', you're statement would need to look similar to:

```
public static const LOCALE_CHANGED_EVENT:String = "localeChangedEvent";

[Bindable(event="localeChangedEvent")]
function foo(param:int):void
{
  var oldValue:int = _fooFighters;
  _fooFighters = param;
  if (oldValue != param) dispatch(new Event(LOCALE_CHANGED_EVENT));
}
```

Now this is over-simplified, but you can hopefully get the idea. As for why it works in the same mxml as the DataGrid, I can only speculate that your dispatched event isn't a defined Event Class but something similar above - just a defined string? Hard to say.

Comment: Hey Mike,

first lets say: Thanks for your answer. 
I think you missunderstood what i want to do.

I don't want to write only a getter function.
The function localeString() should return the founded locale String
(e.g. for path "foo.bar" it should return "Hello World") **or** if no String was founded for the path it should return the path String (e.g. "foo.bar")
The function itself works great. Now i want to bind this function. Because the path String is fix, i can't bind it self.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found out what happens (and understand what Mike was meaning)

The problem is first:

This can not be used:

```
[Bindable(event=LOCALE_CHANGED_EVENT_TYPE)]
```

It should be:

```
[Bindable(event="foo.bar.LocaleChanged")]
```

And the secound fail:

the method should **not be static**, because it dose only worked once at startuptime if it is static.

Thx for you answers :)